# How to solve the Object class being reserved in PHP 7 for yii2 application

Tags: php, yii2, php-7

I moved my Yii2 application from `PHP 5.5` to `PHP 7` but get this error. How can I solve it

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php on line
>   83

I have tried this but doesn't work

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0', '<')) {
    // ensure code works on php < 7.0.0 to not break BC
    class_alias('yii\base\BaseObject', 'yii\base\Object', false);
}
```

Comment: Consider updating the framework, it is already fixed: http://www.yiiframework.com/news/149/yii-2-0-13-is-released/